# Test of stationarity in Dickey and Fuller test

Tags: unit-root, eviews

Why is that in DF (Dickey and Fuller) test, the test verifies that $Tst = 0$  or $Tst < 0$. Why not test $\Phi = 1$ or $\Phi < 1$?

Need some guidance on this

Comment: It would be nice if you wrote down precisely what $Tst$ and $\Phi$ are. From what I know about the unit root tests, the answer is that $Tst=\Phi-1$. Then hypotheses are equivalent.

Comment: you are right. Hypothesis is the same. But why Tst is used instead of $\Phi$. That is my question.

Comment: It is mathematically convenient. I do not think there is any deeper reason, even more, because of the equivalence.